# How to insert lines after second pattern with linux sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I want to insert this block:

```
host client3 {
    hardware ethernet c0:03:03:bc:30:fa;
}
```

after this block:

```
subnet 11.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 11.10.1.2 11.10.1.254;
        group {
            filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";
```

The line: `filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";`
apears multiple times in the file. But only once inside `subnet 11.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {`

Until now I can print the subnet block until the "filename":

```
sed -n -e :a -e '/subnet 11\.10\.0\.0 netmask 255\.255\.255\.0/,/}/{/filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV\.cm";/!{$!{N;ba};};p;}' dhcpd.conf
```

but when I try:

```
sed -n -e :a -e '/subnet 11\.10\.0\.0 netmask 255\.255\.255\.0/,/}/{/filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV\.cm";/!{$!{N;ba};};a\ \thost client3     {\n\thardware ethernet c0:03:03:bc:30:fa;\n\t}\n;}' dhcpd.conf
```

I get:

sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

```
subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.10.0.2 10.10.0.254;
    group {
        filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";
        host client1 {
            hardware ethernet a0:b4:3d:bc:df:fa;
            }
        host client2 {
            hardware ethernet 90:6e:bb:ba:cd:d4;
            }
    }
}
subnet 11.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 11.10.1.2 11.10.1.254;
    group {
        filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";
        host client1 {
            hardware ethernet c0:14:e3:bc:df:fa;
            }
        host client2 {
            hardware ethernet 90:6e:fb:ba:3d:04;
            }
    }
}
subnet 12.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 12.10.2.2 12.10.2.254;
    group {
        filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";
        host client1 {
            hardware ethernet c0:a4:3d:bc:df:fa;
            }
        host client2 {
            hardware ethernet 90:6e:bb:ca:3d:04;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sed `a` for append is difficult to inline.  You could probably get what you want working with a separate command file and `sed -f`.  Make each single line an append.  Alternatively stick the multiline block you want to append in a separate file and `r` command it into the output stream.

Comment: I just want to be sure that this line:
`filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";`

is inside this subnet: `subnet 11.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {`
or at least after thtat line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/subnet 11\.10\.0\.0 netmask 255\.255\.255\.0/{:a;n;/filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV\.cm";/!ba;p;s/\S.*/host client3 {/p;s//    hardware ethernet c0:03:03:bc:30:fa;/p;s//}/}' file
```

This finds the first line containing `subnet 11.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0` and then reads on further until the line containing `filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";`. After printing that line it uses the line as a template to format the required detail.

Another solution, using a preformed insertion file:

```
cat <<\! | sed '/subnet 11\.10\.0\.0 netmask 255\.255\.255\.0/!b;:a;n;/filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV\.cm";/!ba;r /dev/stdin' file
        host client3 {
            hardware ethernet c0:03:03:bc:30:fa;
            }
!
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define newline and tab characters for replacement
NL=$'\n'
NL="\\$NL"
TAB=$'\t'
TAB="\\$TAB"

sed '
:l
N
$!b l
# first of all slurp all lines in the pattern space
# and perform the replacement over the lines
s/subnet 11\.10\.0\.0 netmask 255\.255\.255\.0[^}]*filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV\.cm";/&'"$NL$TAB"'host client3 {'"$NL$TAB$TAB"'hardware ethernet c0:03:03:bc:30:fa;'"$NL$TAB"'}/g
' dhcpd.conf
```

It yields the following output by using the posted lines as `dhcpd.conf`,

```
subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.10.0.2 10.10.0.254;
    group {
        filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";
        host client1 {
            hardware ethernet a0:b4:3d:bc:df:fa;
            }
        host client2 {
            hardware ethernet 90:6e:bb:ba:cd:d4;
            }
    }
}
subnet 11.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 11.10.1.2 11.10.1.254;
    group {
        filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";
        host client3 {
                hardware ethernet c0:03:03:bc:30:fa;
        }
        host client1 {
            hardware ethernet c0:14:e3:bc:df:fa;
            }
        host client2 {
            hardware ethernet 90:6e:fb:ba:3d:04;
            }
    }
}
subnet 12.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 12.10.2.2 12.10.2.254;
    group {
        filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";
        host client1 {
            hardware ethernet c0:a4:3d:bc:df:fa;
            }
        host client2 {
            hardware ethernet 90:6e:bb:ca:3d:04;
            }
    }
}
```

- It initially slurps all the lines at first to process multi lines efficiently.
- It assumes the right curly brace `}` does not appear in the search target block
  to achieve the shortest match in regex.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very good solution. What happens if there are multiple 'filenames' and the one we want is not the first.
like:

`group {
        filename "30M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";
}
group {
        filename "20M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";
}
group {
        filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm";
}`

Comment: Let me confirm your requirent. Do you want to add the 3-line block after any of `group { filename "30M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm"; }`,  `group { filename "20M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm"; }` or `group { filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm"; }` ?

Comment: Insert after `group { filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm"; }`

Comment: My posted answer matches only with `group { filename "10M-5M-OKS2016NOV.cm"; }` and will meet your requirement as is.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is great as a stream editor, that means to process multiple times the same actions. Here you just want to insert once a bloc of text. That would be much simpler (more readable and maintenable) with `ed`:

```
ed dhcpd.conf <<EOF
/subnet 11.10.0.0/
/filename/
a
        host client3 {
            hardware ethernet c0:03:03:bc:30:fa;
            }
.
w
q
EOF
```

Beware: ed is a *file* editor. That means that the dhcpd.conf file will be changed by the above script. Make sure to have a backup if things goes wrong...

Comment: I have to make a script file that automatically do that so, that's why i'm using sed